# Object initialize different in Angular directive than controller?

Tags: object, angularjs, controller, initialization, directive

I've have run into an issue with object initialization differing whether the code is in a controller vs a directive link function.   In the example code below, the "this" parameter being passed in the

```
prop: new Object(this)
```

is a legit Object constructor when the code is run in the controller but is undefined when run in the directive.  Why the difference in execution of the same code?

```
myapp.directive("myDir",function()
{
  var myDir = {
    link: function(scope,element,attrs)
    {
      var obj;

      obj = new Object({
        prop: new Object(this)
      });
    }
  }

  return myDir;
}


myapp.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope)
{
  var obj;

  obj = new Object({
    prop: new Object(this)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of "this" in the declarations is the problem.  Read up on [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) to make sure you understand how it works.

To me it looks like "this" will probably be set to the "myDir" variable in the directive, and the window object in the controller.

Comment: Nope, "this" is within the scope of the containing Object, the "obj" variable.   As I stated, "this" is undefined in the directive and is the expected Object in the controller.   Even if I change "this" to "obj", the results are the same.

Comment: "this" is only assigned in member functions of an object... not inside objects themselves.     Of course it still fails when you change "this" to "obj".. "obj" is null until after the constructor completes, so you're just passing a null.

Comment: Nope, "obj" is not null in either case.  It is undefined in the directive and valid in the controller.

Comment: Right, not null.  "undefined" in either case when you pass it in the constructor.    I'm not talking about the eventual value after the constructor returns.

Comment: There's simply no way to pass a reference to an object to the constructor of that very object.   Re-architect your system.

Comment: I already rewrote the code, I'm attempting to learn why it works, in the presented format, in one place an not in another.